# Python: How to use ffmpeg to read videos(video file or rtsp) and display them using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

I know that if we want to read video file or USB camera or rtsp stream, we can use `cv2.VideoCapture`.
But for some reason, I want to use ffmpeg to do the thing and process obtained images using opencv. So the pseudocode would be:

```py
import cv2
import ffmpeg

videoFile = 'XXX.mp4'

video = ffmpeg.XXX(videoFile)

while True:
    frame = video.read() # this read() function is made up by me
    frameCV = ffmpeg2cv(frame) # this ffmpeg2cv() function is made up by me

    cv2.imshow('frame', frameCV)
```

I have searched a something like https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python. But I still not know how to do this. I think ffmpeg is too hard and there are few online docs unlike opencv. So please help.

Comment: It's some pseudocode made up by me. I want to know how to read videos using ffmpeg and process the obtained images using opencv.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found on the topic:
https://www.bugcodemaster.com/article/extract-images-frame-frame-video-file-using-ffmpeg
They propose a call extracting one image each second called: fps=1
Below they suggest how to extract each frame like: -vf select=eq(pict_type\,I)

So I would suggest using subprocess and try something like this:

```
import subprocess

time = 200  # of your movie
frame_rate = 50
pathToFfmpeg = "SOME\\PATH"
pathToInput = "ANOTHER\\PATH"
pathToOuput = "YET\\ANOTHER\\PATH"

proc = subprocess.run([pathToFfmeg + "\\ffmpeg.exe",
                       "-framerate", str(frame_rate),
                       "-loglevel", "panic",  # Suppress Log
                       "-i", pathToInput + "\\SomeName.avi",

                      # Now copying their code
                      "-vf", "select=eq(pict_type\,I)", 
                      "-vsync", "vfr", pathToOuput + "\\Name.jpg",  
                      "-hide_banner"])  # Specify Output
```

And then you can read the outout images with opencv.

Note: You need all the "" for subprocess

Choose an Output name that contains a counter/iterator.